# TileMill / Mapnik(?) reads numeric column as string

Tags: shapefile, mapnik, tilemill

I have this shapefile: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ywo8ofa02eel3k8/AAC6trz-nw6zD_Hfyzi1jxJHa?dl=0

I have TileMill installed on my computer running Arch Linux. I start the program up by navigating to the directory containing my Tilemill installed and running `./tilemill.sh`.

Once it starts, I open my web browser, Chromium, and navigate to `http://localhost:20009.`

On the bottom right, I click on the "layers" button, select "Add Layer," and follow the instructions to import the shapefile.

The shapefile successfully imports and I can see it on my TileMill project.

Once it's done importing, I click on the "Layers" menu again, then click "Features" for my new "data" layer. And it's clear that TileMill imported the column "value" as a string, not an integer. The "min" and "max" values it lists are correct if I want the column to be read as a string, but since I want them as integer, those values are wrong.

How do I make TileMill read the "value" column of my shapefile as integer?

Comment: Note that you shared your data in shapefile format with just the file with the shp extension. A shapefile is made up of several files with the same name but with different extensions. If you want to share your data, you need to include all the files. Best way is to put everything in a compressed file and upload to your dropbox.

Comment: @Techie_Gus Updated

Answer (score 2):

I do no reproduce your issue. Your values are integer and are recognized as integer when I try using Tilemill 1.1 with your data e.g screenshot. Why can I say this? Because by convention like in a lot of spreadsheet software, when content in a column is left aligned it means it's recognized as a string and if right aligned, it means it's a number.

[image]

I've also checked with GDAL your shp structure using

```
ogrinfo -so -al data.shp
```

And the result confirms your column contains integer.

```
INFO: Open of `/tmp/data.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: data
Metadata:
  DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE=2021-08-23
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 3217
Extent: (-179.148909, 17.883280) - (179.778470, 71.365162)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",
    DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
        SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
    UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]]
GEOID: String (80.0)
NAME_x: String (80.0)
variable: String (80.0)
value: Integer (9.0)
STATEFP: String (80.0)
COUNTYFP: String (80.0)
COUNTYNS: String (80.0)
AFFGEOID: String (80.0)
NAME_y: String (80.0)
NAMELSAD: String (80.0)
STUSPS: String (80.0)
STATE_NAME: String (80.0)
LSAD: String (80.0)
ALAND: Real (24.15)
AWATER: Real (24.15)
```

Comment: I have also checked the data in QGIS and can confirm that the "value" field is integer.